# Update a column value based on others' grouped value?

Tags: sql, mysql

Please help me with a query to update a column value based on others grouped value. Thanks in advance.
Hard to explain so here is an example as I want to update Group value in this table:
Column:

```
    [Id, Delivery, Food, Group]
```

Value:

```
    [1, Ups, Vege, null] 
    [2, DHL, Vege, null] 
    [3, Ups, Meat, null] 
    [4, Ups, Vege, null] 
    [5, DHL, Mushroom, null]
    [6, Fedex, Mushroom, null]
    [7, Ups, Mushroom, null]
    [8, Ups, Meat, null]
```

It's like first group with Delivery then Group value will be incremental by grouped Food.

Expect to Group to be updated as:

```
    [1, Ups, Vege, 1] 
    [2, DHL, Vege, 1] 
    [3, Ups, Meat, 2] 
    [4, Ups, Vege, 1] 
    [5, DHL, Mushroom, 2]
    [6, Fedex, Mushroom, 1]
    [7, Ups, Mushroom, 3]
    [8, Ups, Meat, 2]
```

Seems mysql doesn't support functions like DENSE_RANK(), so it's quite inconvenient.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 'mysql doesn't support functions like DENSE_RANK()' - it does from version 8 , what version are you on?

Comment: @P.Salmon that's new. Thanks but I'm on 5.7 unfortunately.

Comment: There are ways to do this in 5.7 search for mysql dense_rank equivalent. Also please clarify how the rank is logically achieved , eg is it based on id? or food in some way?

Comment: If you wish to try before you upgrade see https://dbfiddle.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Please check my complete query

```
create table tableName  (Id int identity(1,1), Delivery varchar(100), Food varchar(100), [Group] varchar(100))

insert into tableName (Delivery,Food) select   'Ups','Vege'  union all
   select'DHL','Vege'  union all
   select 'Ups','Meat'  union all
   select 'Ups','Vege'  union all
   select'DHL','Mushroom'  union all
  select 'Fedex','Mushroom'  union all
  select 'Ups','Mushroom'  union all
   select'Ups','Meat' 

  -- select * from tableName


 select id,Delivery,food,[group],   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE 
                                    WHEN Food = 'Vege' THEN 1 
                                    WHEN Food = 'Meat' THEN 2
                                    WHEN Food = 'Mushroom' THEN 3
                                    ELSE 4 -- Handle other cases if any
                                END) AS RowNumber
 from tableName 

select * from tableName A inner join  (   select id,    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN Food = 'Vege' THEN 1 
WHEN Food = 'Meat' THEN 2
WHEN Food = 'Mushroom' THEN 3
ELSE 4 -- Handle other cases if any
END) AS RowNumber   from tableName ) As B ON A.id=B.id

update A  set A.[Group]=B.RowNumber 
from tableName A  inner join  (   select id,    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN Food = 'Vege' THEN 1 
    WHEN Food = 'Meat' THEN 2
    WHEN Food = 'Mushroom' THEN 3
    ELSE 4 -- Handle other cases if any
END) AS RowNumber   from tableName ) As B ON A.id=B.id

select * from  tableName
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort. It looks like mysql, which I'm on, doesn't support the DENSE_RANK function.
Plus, Food can be whatever and not necessarily Vege then 1, which comes first can be 1, and so on.

Comment: @LongNguyen seems DENSE_RANK available in both mssql and mysql.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll think about having mysql updated to ver 8 to support DENSE_RANK and the query can go as
`UPDATE tableName AS main
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, Delivery, Food, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Delivery ORDER BY Food) AS group_value FROM tableName
) AS t ON main.id = t.id
 SET main.Group = t.group_value`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, Delivery, Food,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Delivery ORDER BY Delivery desc,food asc) AS GroupValue
FROM tb1 order by id
```

select statement can be used to update table.
the result wont be exact because in your expected order food is neither asc nor desc. if same output is needed then one more column needs to be added in which food order is to be specified. and the field need to be included in the above select statement in place of 'food'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. but the function seems to be not supported by mysql, which I'm on, so it's a bit inconvenient.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll think about having mysql updated to ver 8 to support DENSE_RANK and the query can go as
`UPDATE tableName AS main
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, Delivery, Food, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Delivery ORDER BY Food) AS group_value FROM tableName
) AS t ON main.id = t.id
 SET main.Group = t.group_value`